# Configuring Debezium MySQL connector via env vars

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

The only way to configure a Debezium connector (MySQL in my case) is to send [a config](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mysql.html#example-configuration) to a running Kafka Connect instance via HTTP.

My question is: is it possible to supply this configuration when starting the Connect instance? Via a properties file or (ideally) via env vars?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute a connector worker in *standalone* mode, you can supply configuration via command line (see details [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#standalone-mode)):

> bin/connect-standalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties connector3.properties ...]

For *distributed* mode, you can only use the [REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html). But you can do some automation using tools like [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html).

Comment: Ah, thank you, I missed this somehow. Debezium docs also miss this. Let me create my own Docker image for this and try...

Comment: Maybe this will be a good starting point: https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect

Comment: Yes, that's the image I started with. But it runs Kafka Connect in distributed mode inside, so I'm going to create my own one to start in in standalone mode (as you suggested).

Comment: Hi Alexey, did you make it? Do you have a link if we can use it?